# Will a future C++ standard define a formatted input library analogous to std::print?

Tags: c++, fmt, c++23

C++ 23 introduces the `<print>` library containing `std::print`, which provides improved formatting support over using `std::cout` from `<iostream>`.

I have not been able to find any mention of an analogous library for input.

Are there any proposals for an analagous replacement for `std::cin` for formatted input just as `std::print` may be used in place of `std::cout` for formatted output?

Comment: Are you looking for an "improved" (ie, type-safe) version of [`std::(f|s)scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)?

Comment: FWIW you can see all of the standard proposals here: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/

Comment: "*which provides improved formatting support over using std::cout from <iostream>.*" C++20 already had that. `std::print` is mostly a convenience function beside `std::format(std::cout, ...)`.